# SQL: Count lost values by batch

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table `test` with column `Batch` and `ID`. I would like to count how many IDs are missing in every batch compared with the earliest batch, like comparing batch 2 vs batch 1 for the value of batch 2 below.

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.ID) AS LOST_CNT FROM
(SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE BATCH=1)T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE BATCH=2)T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

I would like to get `lost_cnt` for every batch as the number of batch will increase over time. Something like below does not return what I want.(I understand why, just putting it here as failed attempt)

```
SELECT A.BATCH,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN M.ID ELSE NULL END) AS lost_cnt
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TEST WHERE BATCH=(SELECT MIN(BATCH) FROM TEST)) M 
LEFT JOIN TEST A ON M.ID=A.ID 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: Please add sample input data (ideally as db fiddle or other live script) and expected result. It is less time-consuming than trying to decrypt your intention from verbose description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you want to achieve, but I guess you want to find how many ids are missing compared to the first batch. You can just filter the table with the id in the first batch, count the number of id's in each batch and subtract from the count for the first batch.

```
with t as (
    select *
    from test
    where id in (
        select id
        from test
        where batch = (select min(batch) from test)
    )
)
select
    batch,
    (select count(distinct id)
     from t
     where batch = (select min(batch) from test)
    ) - count(distinct id) as missing
from t
group by batch
order by batch;
```

sample data:

```
batch   id
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       3
2       4
3       3
3       4
```

results:

```
batch   missing
1       0
2       1
3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` analytical function to find the prev batch and then find the id if exists in previous batch using `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT T.BATCH, T.ID
  FROM ( SELECT T.BATCH, T.ID,
           LAG(BATCH) OVER( ORDER BY BATCH) AS PREV_BATCH
      FROM YOUR_TABLE T ) T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM YOUR_TABLE TT
     WHERE TT.BATCH = T.PREV_BATCH
       AND TT.ID = T.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Hive, I would approach this using window functions:

```
with firstbatch (
      select t.*, count(*) over () as num_in_first_batch
      from (select t.*,
                   min(batch) over () as min_batch
            from t
           ) t
      where min_batch = 1
     )
select t.batch,
       count(fb.id) as num_in_first_batch,
       (fb.num_in_first_batch - count(fb.id)) as num_missing_in_first_batch
from t left join
     first_batch fb
     on t.id = fb.id
group by t.batch, fb.num_in_first_batch;
```